# Oracle to_date function with codeigniter

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, to-date

I am using Codeigniter to insert data into an Oracle table which contains a date field.

Sample code looks like this:

```
$upload_details = array("user_name" = $name,
    "age" = $age,
    "date" = 'to_date($date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')'
);
$this->Some_model->insert($upload_details);
```

Now the problem is, to insert date fields into Oracle, i need to use the `to_date` function which is executed in the database. With the above code, the `to_date` function comes out inside single quotes and Oracle throws out an error.

I think the above will work if I use `$this-db->query` in the Codeigniter Model, but am not using that. I am using `$this->db->insert('table_name', $upload_details)`.

So how can I tell codeigniter's `$this->db->insert` to send `to_do` function as it is and not in between single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->db->set('user_name', $name);
$this->db->set('age', $age);
$this->db->set('date',"to_date('$date','dd/mm/yyyy')",false);
$this->db->insert('mytable');
```

Edit: Quotes in $date

Comment: thanks it seems to achieve what I want. However, there is still an error. The above code produces the following SQL: 
`insert into table ("date") Values (16/08/2011, 'dd/mm/yyyy')`
I need the 16/08/2011 to be in between quotes

Comment: Ok, I have figured out how to put the quotes. But, codeigniter still throws out a Database Error and spits out the SQL query. I copy the query and run it in PL/SQL developer, and it runs fine. The row gets inserted. But from codeigniter, it does not. What could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 

SQL QUERIES (This same query I copy pasted into PL/SQL and it ran and inserted the rows. But in CI it gives out error. No error number is given)

Filename: *CI_DIRECTORY*\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: Sorry! I was connecting to a different host. All fixed now. Your solution worked great. Thanks a lot.